# Compare 2 numbers and current day month

Tags: bash

I have a list :

```
$aws events list-rules | awk '{print$6" " $7}'
ENABLED
ENABLED
7 11
1 11
7 11
7 11
4 11
6 11
```

List above : `4 11` means : `4 Nov`

And I would like to compare that list and current time: `$date`

```
Nov  7
```

I have tried but just day comparison only: 
My bash script :

```
!/bin/bash
x=`aws events list-rules |grep "transaction*" |  awk '{print$6}'`
for i in $x
 do
   used=$( date | awk '{print$3}' )
   if [ $i -lt $used ]
   then
          echo $i;

   fi
 done
```

But I donot know how to covert `Nov` -- to --> `11` for comparing but only day but also month.

Please help me, bash or python.

update:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=`aws events list-rules |  awk '{print$7" " $6}'`
for i in $x
 do
   used=$( date +"%m %d" )
   if [ $i -lt $used ]
   then
          echo $i;

   fi
 done
```

But error:

```
./test.sh: line 6: [: too many arguments
./test.sh: line 6: [: too many arguments
./test.sh: line 6: [: too many arguments
./test.sh: line 6: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: What is your expected output after comparison?

Comment: Where are you stuck in python ? (datetime objects can compare with date objects)

Comment: I want to delete all records before today. (it required month and day )

Comment: `for i in $x` will make the first i equal to 7 then 11 ... that will not work for you

Comment: What about `ENABLED` string?

Comment: it include in, I would like to fiter it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` to delete all records that are older than current date:

```
awk -v dt="$(date '+%d %m')" '{fdt = sprintf("%02d%02d", $6, $7)} fdt >= dt' file
```

```
7 11
7 11
7 11
```

Comment: btw, how to delete all record older than 15 minutes

Comment: Your shown data has only day and month so time comparison is not possible. If you have time components available then `date` command can be adjusted accordingly to give you data-time value and then you can use it for comparison in `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
date +"%m %d"
```

And, you can make the comparison logic in your awk, that is, you don't need the for loop, all things can be done in an one-liner. Your codes start the `date` and `awk` processes x times.

- Since you have already had a shell script, you can extract the m and d of the current date, and save in variables. Awk can use shell variables
- You can also execute the `date` and get the output in awk, then in the same awk process, do the comparison.

Comment: just updated the question as follow what you recommend

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I read your changes, it seems that you want the working codes...

Comment: let me try it first

Answer (score 0):

from the manual:

`%m     month (01..12)`

so in your script it should be:

```
used=$(date +%u)
```

if you need the day this would be: `date +%d`